# Foreach Variable Error

Tags: c#

I am clearly just missing something with this.
I have the following:

```
   List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
```

I then fill it with some data and do the following:

```
   foreach (List<string> results in stringList)
```

But it errors claiming that it "cannot convert from type `string` to type `System.Generic.Collections.List<string>`" ...but both are of type `List<string>` so where is the disconnect?  I am sure there must be something very simple I'm clearly doing wrong, but for the life of me I cannot find it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `foreach` should be:

`foreach(string s in stringList)`.

In your code, you're checking for a list of strings in the `stringList`, instead of the strings in the list.

Comment: Ah, yeah it is just one of those days.  I figured it would be something mind-numbingly apparent like that...thank you!

Comment: No problem.  We've all been there.

Comment: better yet, use var instead of string : foreach(var result in stringList)

Answer (score 3):

A for-each iteration gives you the items one at a time, so the type should be `string`, not `List<string>`:

```
foreach (string result in stringList)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use a `foreach` loop in C#, you are iterating through a collection type and performing an operation repeatedly using a single value from that collection. Therefore, for a generic collection type, you want the individual item type in your `foreach` loop.

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
foreach (string stringItem in stringList)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you `foreach` over a list, you are enumerating the elements in the list.  `stringList` contains strings, so you need do to:

```
foreach (string s in stringList)
```

Answer (score 3):

stringList is of type `List<string>`.

That means that every element of your list stringList is going to be a `string`.
So when you do a `foreach (element in stringList)`, element is expected to be a `string`.

The most recommended way to solve your issue is to substitute the `List<string>` inside your foreach for `var`. If you always use `var` in a `foreach` statement, it will automatically consider the correct type (which in this case would be `string` instead of `List<string>`), so you don't have to worry about finding out what type your element is.